# Ruby/Gosu: Issue with calling instance attributes inside loops

Tags: ruby, libgosu

***As a foreword, I want to say that I am very new to programming and this program is definitely not written in the smartest way.***

***Also, I'm using the terminal to show debugging but the program is graphical, as shown near the end.***

In a Gosu program I have an if statement inside the main draw function. 
When this if statement is triggered, it's meant to display several lines of text representing different track names in a music album.
I've been trying to do this using a loop which prints all of these tracks via a single ".draw_text" call. On each iteration it should move down a couple pixels.
The loop is executed once per frame, 60 frames per second.

Inside the loop I'm calling this long chain of arrays/instances:

```
@albums[@current_album_no].tracks[i].name
```

This actually works fine, as shown below, but when I try to use it inside the loop it will crash the program.

The weird thing is, the loop will actually output perfectly fine as shown in the "puts" statements, but will crash AFTER execution.

In a previous version I had this loop in a separate function, so I thought moving the loop to inside the main draw call and using class variables would work instead.
In my mind, this should have removed all variable scope issues, but I'm not sure.

Here's the loop in question:

```
if @current_album_no > 0
   puts "OUTSIDE LOOP: " + @albums[@current_album_no].tracks[1].name.to_s
   for i in 1..@albums[@current_album_no].tracks.length
      puts "INSIDE LOOP: " + @albums[@current_album_no].tracks[i].name.to_s
      @tracks_font.draw_text("Track ##{i}: '#{@albums[@current_album_no].tracks[i].name}'", 225, 100+((i-1)*25), ZOrder::UI, 1.5, 1.5, Gosu::Color::BLACK)
   end
end
```

And the output, showing "success" before the crash:

```
ruby .\gui_music_player.rb

Reading albums file...

Found album #1: 'Black Sands' by 'Bonobo'
Found album #2: 'Ancestral Recall' by 'Christian Scott aTunde Adjuah'

OUTSIDE LOOP: Prelude
INSIDE LOOP: Prelude       ###By this point the program has already crashed
INSIDE LOOP: Kiara
INSIDE LOOP: Kong
INSIDE LOOP: Eyesdown
INSIDE LOOP: El Toro
INSIDE LOOP: We Could Forever
INSIDE LOOP: 1009
INSIDE LOOP: All in Forms
INSIDE LOOP: The Keeper
INSIDE LOOP: Stay the Same
INSIDE LOOP: Animals
INSIDE LOOP: Black Sands
./gui_music_player.rb:97:in `block in draw': undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from ./gui_music_player.rb:96:in `each'
        from ./gui_music_player.rb:96:in `draw'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/gosu-0.14.5-x86-mingw32/lib/gosu/patches.rb:72:in `tick'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/gosu-0.14.5-x86-mingw32/lib/gosu/patches.rb:72:in `tick'
        from ./gui_music_player.rb:182:in `<main>'
```

Line 97 is the "INSIDE LOOP" puts, but without them it gives the same error:

```
ruby .\gui_music_player.rb

Reading albums file...

Found album #1: 'Black Sands' by 'Bonobo'
Found album #2: 'Ancestral Recall' by 'Christian Scott aTunde Adjuah'

./gui_music_player.rb:99:in `block in draw': undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from ./gui_music_player.rb:96:in `each'
        from ./gui_music_player.rb:96:in `draw'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/gosu-0.14.5-x86-mingw32/lib/gosu/patches.rb:72:in `tick'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/gosu-0.14.5-x86-mingw32/lib/gosu/patches.rb:72:in `tick'
        from ./gui_music_player.rb:182:in `<main>'
```

With line 99 being the "@tracks_font.draw_text" call.

Now what I actually want to happen is something like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2pZp.png
But with different track names of course.

That screenshot was made by changing the "i" here:

```
'#{@albums[@current_album_no].tracks[i].name}'
```

...into a "1".

So the code is able to show a complete list, just not with different track names.

Comment: When `i == @albums[@current_album_no].tracks.length` `tracks[i]` will equal `nil` because `i` is out of range (e.g, `a = [1,2,3]; a[2] #=> 3; a[a.size] #=> a[3] => nil`). That's consistent with the error message, as `nil` does not have a method `name`. You could write `for i in 0..@albums[@current_album_no].tracks.length - 1` or  `(0..@albums[@current_album_no].tracks.length-1).each do |i| ... end` or `@albums[@current_album_no].tracks.length.times do |i| ... end`. Rubyists don't use `for` loops. Better to use an enumerator (here `each` or `times`) with a (`do ... end` or `{ ... }`) block.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Cary, you got it. I had actually put a dummy item in the [0] position of both @albums[] and tracks[], so `for i in 1..(@albums[@current_album_no].tracks.length - 1)` is what ended up working.
I'll try to avoid using for loops in future but for now I'll leave this in its current state.
Thanks again.

Comment: If you have found a clear answer that might help other people in the future, consider writing an answer to your own question :-)